# Why is Jasmine not finding the String on my page

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I am writing some Jasmine tests and `toContain` is not finding a String on the page.  Here is one of them:

```
  it('should contain Superhero', function() {
    expect(el).toContain('Superhero');
  });
```

Here is the value of `el` which is a `Jquery` object:
[image]

Also, here is the error in `Karma`:

```
Chrome 32.0.1700 (Mac OS X 10.8.5) marvelApp directives detail.window.directive should contain Superhero FAILED
    TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'indexOf'
        at null.<anonymous> (/Users/mhamm/Developer/marvel/test/mainCtrlSpec.js:61:20)
Chrome 32.0.1700 (Mac OS X 10.8.5): Executed 1 of 0 (1 FAILED) ERROR (0 secs / 10 mins 37.377 secs)
```

Why does `Jasmine` not see the value Superhero in my `el`?

Comment: `[object Object] has no method 'indexOf'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the method `toContain` expects that the function `expect` got a string, not a jQuery Object:

```
  it('should contain Superhero', function() {
    expect(el.html()).toContain('Superhero');
  });
```

Thats why you get this error:

> `[object Object] has no method 'indexOf'`

Answer (score 0):

```
it('should contain Superhero', function() {
  expect(el.text()).toContain('Superhero');
});
```